How to write lead sheet with partial repeat?
I'm writing a lead sheet with this form:
Verse-B-B-C
Verse2-B-B-C
Solo-C
Verse-B-C-Outro
The second verse have some different notes and phrasing, and I decided to write it separately to avoid confusion. Is this already efficient and clear enough, or there are better ways to do it?


I assume the score you posted is just an outline and you don't have sections like verse and outro of only one bar lengths. How long are verses 1 and 2 in actual measure counts?

@MichaelCurtis They have 10 measure each.

"Is this already efficient and clear enough" —Sometimes "efficient" and "clear" are opposites! Personally I'd rather just have each segment notated separately, with line breaks, and textual instructions telling me which order to play them in, as is often done with chord-symbol sheets.
Also, don't underestimate the benefit of writing things out. I mean, we could technically always notate all things without using any repeats, DCs, DSs, etc., just one note after the other. Why don't we? Well, if the music gets too long there may be unwieldy page turns or too many pages on the stand. And sometimes repeats or D.C. help make the structure more evident ("Oh look, this is a da capo aria" or "Oh look, it's sonata-allegro form"). Aside from these concerns, these "play it again" notations serve only the composer/typesetter/publisher. When handwriting a draft, repeats can save time and hand cramps. When typesetting a final version, they can help save on paper costs.
But these notations do no favors to the sight-reading performer. Our basic mode of operation is "Play this note; now play the one right after it." Repeat notations tell us "Play this note, now instantly scan the earlier material to find a place to jump back to." If you made note of this spot when you first passed it, or if the jump isn't too far back, this can be trivial, but if there are multiple "backwards repeat" signs throughout the piece, or if you make a large jump back several pages to something other than the very beginning, then this task can take several seconds of visual scanning or even physical page-turning. For an ensemble of beginners, they can guarantee catastrophe as some percentage of the group forgets the repeat, or as some take one when they shouldn't. (And sometimes for professionals as well!) For the performer, this isn't "efficiency."
Without knowing the actual musical material you're working with and the real length of the sections it's hard to know what's best, but I would probably go with:

Print "Verse, B section with repeats, C section." Put a D.C. at the end.
Print the lyrics of Verse 2 under the lyrics of Verse 1. Use small notes to indicate any minor differences of musical material. Make a textual note that the repeats around the B section should be taken both times, since it's common to skip repeats after a D.C.
Print out all the rest of the piece fully; C, Verse, B, Outro.


Well said. I’m a fan of minimal to no road maps, especially when having to sight read. In my experience, many hours have been wasted in rehearsals trying to figure them out. Even seasoned pros will sometimes miss a DS or a repeat ending, etc. Nowadays, writing something out in linear form isn’t a big issue. With computer notation, it’s just as easy to copy/paste 8 bars as it is to put in a repeat or a DS, no writers cramp!

@JohnBelzaguy Not to mention, I know many folks who play from iPads with foot pedals, so extra pages and page turns are no problem, but flipping back several pages at a time is more problematic.

I was thinking about mentioning that as well. I’ve gotten to the point where ~95% of what I read on gigs is on my iPad with a Bluetooth foot switch.

Having multiple labeled sections which are very conspicuously marked can be better than having things written out if e.g. the length of a performance may need to be adjusted to coincide with something like a procession or spoken introduction whose duration might not be known in advance.  Having conspicious spots which say, in essence, "If as you approach this mark, the band leader is looking up, go to X.  If staring straight ahead, go to Y.  Otherwise continue onward" may be better than having fully written out music and having to figure out what to do if the procession or speech is done...

...but there's another 45 seconds worth of music remaining, or if one would reach the end of the music while the procession or introductory speech is still ongoing.

I'm not sure how others will react, but I want to offer this suggestion. Write out separated sections with textual instructions for play order.

I've made hand written lead sheets similar to this for my personal use.
Name the section however you like.
I used double bar lines to demark sections. In Musescore I used line breaks and spacers so each section begins at the left margin. I think this helps visually indicate separate sections rather than a continuous flow.
For things repeated more than once, consider using the dotted slash sign...

...which means simply repeat the preceding measure. You can use the sign multiple times. I think that's clearer for repeating a measure four times, instead of using barline repeats with a text annotation to repeat four times.
There is a similar sign over a bar line which means repeat two measures of music...

My justification for this kind of score comes from instructions I have seen in old French keyboard music, I seem to remember it used for some rondos, but I also have this example from a Dover edition of keyboard music by F. Couperin. Note the textual play order instructions at the bottom of the page...

This is also in line with what a composer told me a long time ago. If you have some special instructions with no obvious traditional musical notation symbols, just write out instructions in plain English.
